# Unfamiliar Syntax, TypeScript, Promises

Tags: typescript, promise

I am working on understanding the [Angular Google Maps (AGM) Library](https://angular-maps.com/) on GitHub, specifically a particular section in their [`lazy-map-api-loader.ts`](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/packages/core/services/maps-api-loader/lazy-maps-api-loader.ts) file:

```
this.promise = new Promise<void>((resolve: Function, reject: Function) => {
  (<any> window)[callbackName] = () => { // I've simplified this line a bit.
    resolve();
  };

  script.onerror = (error: Event) => {
    reject(error);
  };
});
```

Eventually, the above promise is returned to the caller of this method; however, the piece that I don't understand is the cast (?) `(<any>window)[callbackName] =` syntax, seen above.

It *looks* like the are trying to access a particular property on the `window` object (with the name equivalent to the value of `callback`) and assign the property to a function that will `resolve` the promise in which the definition of anonymous the function is found.

From what I can see, however, the the function that is assigned to that property is never called in the repository.

What is happening above?

Comment: This is how [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) works. (Admittedly, both of those callbacks should `delete (<any>window)[callbackName]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<any>` is just used to avoid any property access issues since the callback name doesn't actually exist on `window`. The bracket syntax is used because `callbackName` is a variable.

This would be the same as:

```
this._windowRef.getNativeWindow().angular2GoogleMapsLazyMapsAPILoader
```

...however this would result in an type error if you didn't cast to `any`. My guess is that `callbackName` is used since it's a lot easier to type and it's used multiple times.

As for when this actually gets called, [See the script tag construction](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/packages/core/services/maps-api-loader/lazy-maps-api-loader.ts#L174) which will result in *something* like:

```
<script src="https://googleapis.com/maps?callback=angular2GoogleMapsLazyMapsAPILoader"</script>
```

Google APIs itself will call this callback function once the script finishes loading. The property needs to exist on `window` in order for it to be called.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! Didn't know that could call a callback that way.